# Generic parameter from interface is hidden in the implementation

Tags: java, generics

I have following interfaces and implementations:

```
public interface InputDO<T> {

    T getWrappedObject();

}
```

And many extended interfaces like for example:

```
public interface InputPage<T> extends InputDO<T> {

    String getName();

}
```

and an implementing class

```
public class InputPageImpl<T> implements InputPage<T> {

    T wrappedObject;

    String name;

    @Override
    public T getWrappedObject() {
        return wrappedObject;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

}
```

Then I have an interface for a data query object

```
public interface DataQuery<T extends InputDO<?>> {

    void fetchResources(T object );

}
```

And one of its implementation:

```
public class TestPageDataQuery implements DataQuery<InputPage<?>>

    public void fetchResources( InputPage<?> page ) {
        System.out.println(page.getName());
    }   

}
```

Now I would like to have a map of the DataQuery objects associated with the type they are handling. So I have context object with a map like this:

```
public class Context {

    private final Map<Class<? extends InputDO<?>>, DataQuery<? extends InputDO<?>>> DATA_QUERIES = new HashMap<>();

    public <T extends InputDO<?>> void registerDataQuery( Class<T> clazz, DataQuery<T> dataQuery ) {

        DATA_QUERIES.put( clazz, dataQuery );

    }
}
```

However, I get a compilation error when I try something like this:

```
context.registerDataQuery( InputPageImpl.class, new TestPageDataQuery() );
```

Because InputPageImpl is a generic I cannot do something like:

```
InputPageImpl<?>.class.
```

When I rewrite the TestPageDataQuery to also be a generic type and call the register method like this, it works:

```
configuration.registerDataQuery( InputPageImpl.class, new TestPageDataQuery<InputPageImpl>() );
```

However, I get a compilation warning about the raw types. Because I don't care about the wrapped object in the dataquery I could use SuppressWarnings but I am still wondering if there is a better solution for this.